# underscore js groupby array inside JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have assigned a task to group data in angular js using underscore js.

My JSON :

```
$scope.myData= {
"buslist":
    {
        "code":"1",
        "message":"Success",
        "fromStationCode":"71",
        "searchResult": [
            {
                "arrivalTime": "17:00:00",
                "availableSeats": "42",
                "boardingPointDetails": [
                    {
                        "code": "1631",
                        "name": "Koyambedu",
                        "time": "09:30:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "code": "961296",
                        "name": "Nerkundram",
                        "time": "09:45:00"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "arrivalTime": "18:00:00",
                "availableSeats": "32",
                "boardingPointDetails": [
                    {
                        "code": "2084",
                        "name": "Adyar",
                        "time": "09:30:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "code": "961296",
                        "name": "Madurai",
                        "time": "09:45:00"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm unable to group data using "name" field using underscore js.
  I tried :

```
$scope.groups = _.groupBy($scope.myData,function(element) {
    return element.searchResult.boardingPointDetails.name;
});
```

But it fails. Need help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because `searchResult` AND `boardingPointDetails` are arrays, not objects - so `return element.searchResult[0].boardingPointDetails[0].name;` will probably work for the first elements inside those arrays

Comment: how can I make it get works for all element..@Alon Eiten

Comment: It's hard to answer that, because you want to group by multiple keys - So you need to show us the desired output you expecting  from the group by function.

Comment: My output should be like this:                                                          name:"madurai" : { availableSeats:"32" , availableSeats:"45" }, name:"Adyar"    :{ availableSeats:"45" ,availableSeats:"32", availableSeats:"49" }

Comment: First group them in an array with data on the same level of nesting like: [{name: "madurai", availableSeats:"32"},{name: "Adyar", availableSeats:"32"}]. Then group them by name, getting name to the higher nesting level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution for your problem :

```
var tempResult = [];
_.each($scope.myData.buslist.searchResult, function(result) {
    _.each(result.boardingPointDetails, function(detail) {
        var item = { name: detail.name, availableSeats: result.availableSeats };
        tempResult.push(item); // make an array of items with needed data on same nesting level
    });
});

var endResult = _.groupBy(tempResult, 'name');  // group the items by name
```

See it working for your situation : [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JpPjA/350/)